# Полное удаление пакетов Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Как правильно удалять полностью пакеты в Ubuntu,со всеми конфигами и так далее?
На данный момент нахожу все файлы и папки с пом`ощью find / -name 'val'`,но когда много файлов неудобно руками мучаться удалять,если ли какое решение эффективнее и проще?

Comment: уточните, про что именно речь: про какие пакеты, про какие файлы.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get purge val
```

Вот выдержка из man'а:

> purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
>      purged (any configuration files are deleted too).

Comment: Всеравно остаются файлы,мне желательно удалить все что связано с val

Comment: Можно поподробнее, какие файлы остаются?